# Force DataGrid row refresh without INPC

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a collection of items that do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (not something I can change). Once I've changed properties in a specific item, how can I force a refresh of all bindings in the corresponding row?

I don't want to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` and replace the original item with a new item of the same type but with the new data, because then I will lose the current selection. I could set the `SelectedItem` with the new replacement item, but then I will trigger the `SelectionChanged` event when I replace the item.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer that comes to my mind is to wrap your collection into a ICollectionViewSource and call Refresh() when you receive updates on your items:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICollectionView MyCollectionView { get; set; }

    private List<NotNotifiableObject> internalList;
    private Random _rnd;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        internalList = new List<NotNotifiableObject>();
        MyCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(internalList);

        _rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        {
            internalList.Add(new NotNotifiableObject { Age = i, Name = "John Doe " + i });
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = _rnd.Next(0, 31);
        var objectToUpdate = internalList[index];
        objectToUpdate.Name = objectToUpdate.Name + " | " + DateTime.Now;
        MyCollectionView.Refresh();
    }
}

internal class NotNotifiableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You just have to bind your datagrid to this ICollectionView property

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionView}" ></DataGrid>
```

This works just fine but can impact performance if your list has a lot of items which are frequently updated

Comment: Performance is an issue here, so I can't  refresh the entire collection. Is there some way to refresh a single item with `ICollectionView`?

Comment: Make sense. Take a look to my second proposal ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Items.Refresh() method from DataGrid after updating item, it does not raise SelectionChanged event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item" + i.ToString(), Value = i });
        }

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = Items[1];
        item.Name = "Item2 updated";
        item.Value = 22;
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }

    private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("dataGrid_SelectionChanged");
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                  Grid.Row="0" 
                  SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonUpdate" 
                Content="Update" 
                Width="100" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Click="buttonUpdate_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you change the perspective : act on the object itslef rather than the collection.

Can't  you create a INPC object that would wrap the properties of your none INPC object ? Then, when you receive your updated object, you update the INPC object (I call them Adapters) instead ? And your collection would hold a list of those Adapters.

Actually, It would help to have your code (and in particular the section where you update your none INPC objects) for a better answer.

But keep in mind, that in general, it is better to use Adapters (or decorators, whatever their names) to present your data to your views.

The first reason is that you always have specific presentation needs (aggregate properties, translated values, etc.) that your original business object won't be able to hold.

So using adapters offers at least these two solutions : 1) transform a non INPC object into a notifiable one and 2) provide a more flexible, presentation oriented, object that would be able to present data as needed for the views.

Comment: I cannot create an adapter, because this functionality is meant to be used for a number of different types.